# Commit button is Greyed out on VS code

Tags: flutter, macos, visual-studio-code

I am using a macbook air M2, when I clicked commit the previous time my computer showed me some warning which I didn't read and clicked OK now the commit button is greyed out.

this is what it shows
[image]

Is there a way I can undo the change or a settings option which i can go to

Comment: first add, then you can commit. You can press on `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this commands on terminal :

```
git add .

git commit m-'your commit '

git push
```

Comment: I did its not working

Comment: what the error that they show you on the terminal.

Comment: I restarted my device and tried the commands you wrote above and voila! it works now

Comment: i'm glade you solve it.